# Problem Serializing Node Set to Print Label

Tags: serialization, xquery, exist-db

I am a Digital Archivist and was recently hired at a new organization. Turns out they had a very critical database go down 1.5/2 years ago and I've been helping them get it back up and running. The database utilizes exist-DB. I've gotten everything all set except for one final piece... printing box/folder labels. This is the snippet of code that deals with that:

```
declare function arc3:view($form) as xs:string* 
{
(:  let $real-user1 := session:get-attribute("user")
    let $real-password := session:get-attribute("password") 
    let $new := session:set-current-user($real-user1, $real-password)
:)  

    let $s := arc3log:add-log-message("at top of local view")
    let $file-name := $form/data/file
    let $short-name := $form/data/shortTitle

(:  let $current := xmldb:get-current-user()
    let $temp := concat($current,"-temp-file.xml")
    let $d := xmldb:store("/db/apps/archives3/data/", $temp, $form)
    let $tempFile := concat("/db/apps/archives3/data/",$temp)
    let $rec := util:eval("doc($tempFile)")  
:)  
    let $rec := $form
  
    let $rec := transform:transform($rec, "xmldb:exist:///apps/archives3/resources/styles/printLabel.xsl", <parameters><param name="filename" value="{$file-name}"/></parameters>)

    let $query := if($form/data/type='folder') then concat($rec, "order by number($f/did/container[@type='box']),number($f/did/container[@type='folder']) return <folder><box>{$f/did/physloc/text()}</box><folderNumber>{$f/did/container[@type='folder']/text()}</folderNumber><folderTitle>{$f/did/unittitle/text()}</folderTitle><date1>{$f/did/unitdate/text()}</date1><Accession>{$f/acqinfo/p/num/text()}</Accession><Title>{$f/ancestor::ead/archdesc/did/unittitle[@type='short']/text()}</Title></folder>") else concat($rec,") order by number($boxes) return    for $box in $boxes      let $date2 := if (doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box]/../unitdate/string-length(@normal) > 4) then  max(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,6)) else max(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,1,4))
                        
                        
    let $date3 := min(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,1,4))  let $f := doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box][1]   let $d := doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//container[.[@type='box'] = $box][last()]  let $line := $f/ancestor::c[@level='series']/did/unittitle/text()   let $line2 := $d/ancestor::c[@level='series']/did/unittitle/text()  let $test1 := if ($date3=$date2)                     then <date>{$date2}</date>                 else <date>{$date3}-{$date2}</date>     let $test2 := if ($line=$line2) then <line>{$line}</line>   else <line>{$line}-{$line2}</line>  return <box><accession>{$f/../../acqinfo/p/num/text()}</accession><fonds><name>{$f/ancestor::archdesc/did/origination/text()}</name></fonds>            <title><prime>{$f/ancestor::archdesc/did/unittitle[1]/text()}</prime>{$test2} {$test1} </title> <container>{$d/text()}</container> <stack>{$f/../physloc/text()}</stack></box>")
 
    let $s := arc3log:add-log-message("did transform")

    let $query := if($form/data/type='box' and contains($rec,'physloc')) then  concat($rec, ") order by number($boxes)
return  
for $box in $boxes      
let $date2 := if(max(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../unitdate/string-length(@normal) > 5)       then max(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,6)) else max(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,-1,4)) 
let $date3 := min(doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../unitdate/substring(@normal,1,4)) 
let $f := doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../container[@type='box'][1]
let $d := doc('",$file-name,"')/ead//dsc//physloc[. = $box]/../container[@type='box'][last()] 
let $line := $f/ancestor::c[@level='series']/did/unittitle/text() 
let $line2 := $d/ancestor::c[@level='series']/did/unittitle/text() 

let $test1 := if ($date3=$date2) then <date>{$date2}</date> else <date>{$date3}-{$date2}</date>
let $test2 := if ($line=$line2) then <line>{$line}</line> else <line>{$line}-{$line2}</line>

return <box><accession>{$f/../../acqinfo/p/num/text()}</accession><fonds><name>{$f/ancestor::archdesc/did/origination/text()}</name></fonds>            <title><prime>{$f/ancestor::archdesc/did/unittitle[1]/text()}</prime>{$test2} {$test1} </title> <container>{$d/text()}</container> <stack>{$f/../physloc/text()}</stack></box>") else $query



    let $s := arc3log:add-log-message(concat("this Query is: ", $query))
    
    let $recs := util:eval($query)
    let $s := arc3log:add-log-message(concat("this result is: ", $recs))    
    
    let $blank-label := if ($form/data/type="folder") then <folder xmlns="" /> else <box xmlns="" />

    let $count := $form/data/startLabel
    let $add := (
      for $p in 1 to (xs:int($count)-1)
       return $blank-label
        )
    
    let $label :=   if($form/data/type ="folder" ) then
                    <FLD xmlns="">{$add} { $recs} </FLD>
                else 
                    <boxlbl xmlns="">{$add}{$recs}</boxlbl>  
                    
    let $s := arc3log:add-log-message(concat("the label is: ", $label))

    let $s := if ($form/data/type ="folder") then file:serialize($label,concat("../Labels-",$short-name,".xml"), "method=xml, omit-xml-declaration=no, media-type=application/xml, indent=no") 
                else 
                file:serialize($label, concat("../Boxes-",$short-name,".xml"),"method='xml',omit-xml-declaration='no',media-type='application/xml',indent='no'") 

    return
        if ($form/data/type ="folder") then 
            concat("Labels-",$form/data/shortTitle,".xml")
        else 
            concat("Boxes-",$form/data/shortTitle,".xml")
             
    
};
```

It fails to create the labels and gives me an error "ERROR Cannot serialize file. A problem occurred while serializing the node set: ../Boxes-.xml (Permission denied) [at line 66, column 33] In function: arc3:view(item()*) [25:27:/db/apps/archives3/modules/arc3.xql]

I updated the line/column to reflect the location in my pasted snippet.

Any help with this would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Which version of eXist-db?

Comment: This is version 2.2. Keeping it on this version due to having to change a bunch of deprecated code. Just need to get this database going until I can implement an entirely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

The "Permission denied" portion of the error message is the key indicator of the cause of this error. eXist-db's [`file:serialize`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=file:serialize) function can only be called by the "admin" user or a member of the "dba" group. Either you need to make an explicit call to the [`xmldb:login`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=xmldb:login) function (here or in the main module that calls this `arc3:view` function), or you need to set the [setUid or setGid](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/security#special-perm) permissions on that main module. To do so, use the [`sm:chgrp`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=sm:chgrp) function to ensure the the main module is owned by the dba group, and the [`sm:chmod`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=sm:chmod) function. Set `$path` to the path to the main module that calls `arc3:view` and `$mode` set to `g+xs`. For example, `sm:chgrp(xs:anyURI("/db/my-main-module.xq"), "dba")` and `sm:chmod(xs:anyURI("/db/my-main-module.xq"), "g+s")`.

(The commented-out call to the [`session:set-current-user`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/index.html?q=session:set-current-user) function could also set the user, but it assumes an HTTP session is active, and the username and password would need to be passed as session attributes. Only you would know if these assumptions are valid. The methods I described above do not make these assumptions.)

Comment: Thanks for your help Joe. I attempted to go the simple route first and see what would happen if I uncommented the user/password function. It didn't work and ended up giving me a brand new error (posted in next comment). I don't know much yet about Xquery yet, but am pretty good at learning on the fly which is how I've gotten this far. How do I change the sticky bit? Is it just chmod-ing to 1000 via the terminal?

Comment: Error after implementing login:

err:XPTY0004 checking function parameter 1 in call session:set-current-user(untyped-value-check[xs:string, $real-user1], untyped-value-check[xs:string, $real-password]): XPTY0004: The actual cardinality for parameter 1 does not match the cardinality declared in the function's signature: session:set-current-user($user-name as xs:string, $password as xs:string) xs:boolean?. Expected cardinality: exactly one, got 0. [at line 135, column 47, source: /db/apps/archives3/modules/arc3.xql] In function: arc3:view(item()*) [25:27:/db/apps/archives3/modules/arc3.xql]

Comment: Luckily, eXist-db 2.2 introduced the setUid and setGid functions (which I initially referred to as "sticky bit" by mistake). I've updated the answer with instructions on how to use it.